# App Crashes on launching specific activity

Tags: android-activity, crash

My app crashes every time I try to launch the RegisterActivity. I have swapped out several other activities and the button launches them. Just not RegisterActivity. It is in the Manifest and there are no errors. I cannot figure out the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Code follows:

```
// Link to Register Screen
btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View v) {

          Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
          startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The Activity that crashes the app:

```
    package com.dip.allnavyinfo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set View to register.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);

        // Listening to Login Screen link
        loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // Closing registration screen
                // Switching to Login Screen/closing register screen
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.dip.allnavyinfo; is package not installed?
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4417)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.dip.allnavyinfo; is package not installed?
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:369)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dip.allnavyinfo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>  
        </activity>



        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/main" >
        </activity>


        <activity 
            android:name=".Bibs"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bibs" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/lgnlbl">
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/reglbl">
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- make sure that you have defined the activity RegisterActivity  in your Manifest

2- change this :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

into

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Its 100% in the manifest. With that code I get this error: The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (Intent)

Comment: check now i have edited my answer
change startActivityForResult into startActivity(intent)

Comment: Same crash. Same output:
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.dip.allnavyinfo; is package not installed?
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)

Comment: 08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4417)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 06:44:15.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: this problems states that you have an issue with your pakage name, did you refactor the package names recently, make sure all the package names are correct and post your Manifest.xml if possible

Comment: What do you mean the package name? I havent touched anything about the package name?

Comment: and I found it..... missing ">"
        <activity 
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/reglbl">
        </activity>
Nevermind...130am...seeing things

Comment: this is what i meant by the package name error 
android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.dip.allnavyinfo; is package not installed? 

as per your logcat

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by sorting out my async tasks. I was making two calls in the same thread, once I separated them into two threads the problem was solved.